# Etymology of phrase, "to get the better/best of"

Tags: etymology, phrase-origin

What is the origin of the term, "to get the better/best" of? While I've looked at some sources, they say the meaning without giving the etymology of the phrase. Since the meaning has to do with controlling someone, maybe it's considered getting "the best" of someone in the sense of "making the most" out of them. Of course, I'm not sure how "the better of" would fit in that sense.

What is the origin of this expression?

Comment: From the [Etymonline entry for ***better*** **(n.1)**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/better#etymonline_v_42932): To get *the better of* someone "obtain mastery or victory over" is from **1650s**, from *better* in a sense of "superiority, mastery," which is recorded from mid-15c.

Comment: From the [Etymonline entry for ***best*** **(v)**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/best#etymonline_v_42782): "to get the better of, outdo, surpass," **1863**, from [best](https://www.etymonline.com/word/best?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_11074) (adj.). Related: *Bested*; *besting*.